# Preventing the Windows task bar from appearing when a full screen app active

Tags: delphi, winapi, powerpoint, taskbar

We have an application that shows a small "always on top" window. This works fine in general. Like other applications, when it is active, the TaskBar shows it as selected.

Now add PowerPoint in slideshow mode into the mix. Our window is visible, and PowerPoint has the whole screen. All fine. Until, that is, you click on our window, and Windows 7 shows the Taskbar with our app selected. The Taskbar is brought to the front of PowerPoint's full screen display, and this is causing confusion in the users. Particularly as they will then click on the icon on the taskbar which causes our app to be minimized.

If we use the ExStyle CreateParams to set WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW and ensure that WS_EX_APPWINDOW is not set, then we don't appear in the Taskbar, but the Taskbar is still brought to the front anyway. If it makes any difference, the language used is Delphi, XE version.

The question then is how we might stop Windows from showing the Taskbar over the top of PowerPoint when our Always on Top app is focussed.

Comment: That seems like perfectly normal Windows behavior to me. Can you think of another program that works the way you want yours to?

Comment: @Rob No, I can't find any other app that does what I want. I know a few that would benefit from it though. And it didn't happen in XP.

Comment: Is this a popup window or an overlapped window, I think it should be a popup window..

Comment: if the user can't get the taskbar to show, how do they switch apps?

Comment: @David There is no intention to stop the user getting the task bar to show - all the usual ways will still work. What I'd like to stop is the automatic showing of the task bar when an app gains focus away from PowerPoint. The user doesn't want it shown. Imagine the app on top is controlling powerpoint to jump to another slide. They click, the app does its stuff, but the task bar appeared and messed it up.

Comment: @Sertac I've just tried ensuring the WS_POPUP is set, and it is. No difference. I've also experimented with MainFormOnTaskBar (a Delphi thing) and no matter how it is hidden it doesn't affect it. The TaskBar always comes visible.

Comment: I'd remove the dephi tag.  I don't think it's relevant, and it may be limiting your audience.

Comment: I haven't done it, but you can use different desktop or window-station (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687107(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: This is why there is no progrmatic access to the "Recently Used" or "Pinned" items in the Start Menu, and on the Taskbar. Why there is no event when your notification area balloon is closed. Why Microsoft makes your app flash in the taskbar, rather than letting it steal focus. This is why Microsoft has stopped letting developers do whatever they want. Developers used to be trusted to do the right thing.

Comment: @Ian What about this do you think is not doing the right thing? First, this is a customer who is asking for this, not me. The "right thing" is to keep the full screen app full screen, and not bring up irrelevant information that confuses the presenter and audience. (If you are referring to an answer, comment to that!)

Comment: @mj2008 Customers ask for wrong things, and Microsoft now does not allow developers to do some things, and goes so far as to *prevent* what the paying customer wants. If giving focus to your application makes a taskbar appear, then don't give focus to your application; take away the window's **stay on top** attribute. The problem with allowing developers to *not* have the taskbar appear when they switch application is: the taskbar might not appear when the user switches applications. You may not like the behavior of Windows, but there are some basic ground rules that i don't want you breaking.

Comment: And while people might try to circumvent some of the basic rules (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192415/preventing-the-windows-task-bar-from-appearing-when-a-full-screen-app-active/7196216#7196216), Microsoft reserves the right to prevent applications from intentionally breaking the rules.

Answer (score 2):

As it's already written in the previous comments, this is the Windows behavior.

Personnaly, I use several screens to avoid this behavior:

- first screen has the taskbar
- and I display my powerpoint to another screen without the taskbar (extended desktop).

By the way, I manage what you are expecting like this... this is not really pretty, but it works, I think, as you expect:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, AppEvnts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    aplctnvnts1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure aplctnvnts1Deactivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure aplctnvnts1Activate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SetTaskBarVisible(bVisible: Boolean);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.SetTaskBarVisible(bVisible: Boolean);
const
//  START_BUTTON_LABEL = 'Démarrer';
  START_BUTTON_LABEL = 'Start';
begin
  if bVisible then
  begin
    ShowWindow(FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil               ), SW_SHOW);
    ShowWindow(FindWindow('Button'       , START_BUTTON_LABEL), SW_SHOW);
  end
  else if FindWindow('screenClass', nil) > 0 then  // Fullscreen PowerPoint
  begin
    ShowWindow(FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil               ), SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow(FindWindow('Button'       , START_BUTTON_LABEL), SW_HIDE);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.aplctnvnts1Activate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetTaskBarVisible(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.aplctnvnts1Deactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetTaskBarVisible(True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetTaskBarVisible(True);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yike! That is more than I would want to do for this. I don't want to stop the user getting the task bar should they want to. Just to stop it appearing when it has no good reason to.

Comment: If your app loses focus, the taskbar reappears... you can even add a button in your app to make it visible...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your applet to appear and act as through it's a floating toolbar associated with Powerpoint, so that the user thinks they're still using Powerpoint rather than a separate application?

One way to provide this illusion is to use whe [WS_EX_NOACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) style on the window: when the user clicks it, you should still get clicks that you can handle to trigger your functionality, but Powerpoint should remain the active window.

Note that this only works if all your app needs to do is handle single clicks; if you need to receive keyboard input, you're going to have to become active and take focus, and windows will display the taskbar as usual.

(As an aside, also consider implementing a hotkey using RegisterHotKey so that keyboard users who can't click the window can still access whatever this functionality is.)

Comment: Hmm, a most interesting option. I do need more complex interaction, but maybe I could change the mode according to what is happening.